# Where are .Net 4.5.2 tools installed?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5.2

I'm having problem with LC.exe when building our application in Visual Studio 2013. When I started searching for LC.exe, I found the latest one installed under "c:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools". I have both 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 installed. But I don't see a "NETFX 4.5.2 Tools" folder anywhere. When I uninstalled 4.5.1, all those tools are gone, and the latest LC.exe I can get is for .Net 4.5, which I also have installed. But where is the one installed by 4.5.2? I've tried removing and reinstalling 4.5.2 and still cannot find any tools from it. Does this mean I have to have both 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 installed? Is there a list of files (and installed paths) installed by each of the .Net pack? I understand from 4.0 onward .Net install should be in-place replacement, but I think the LC.exe in 4.5.1 path is 4.5.1, not 4.5.2 version (with version number 4.0.30319.33440).

Thanks for any info or pointers!

Comment: what about `C:\>dir /s /a lc.exe`?

Comment: I'm assuming this is equivalent to searching for "lc.exe" in Windows Explorer. It's not that I don't have lc.exe. I can see multiple lc.exe under different "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows" sub-folders. But I don't see an "bin\NETFX 4.5.2 Tools" folder after installing the Developer Pack for 4.5.2. Actually I just tried re-installing Visual Studio 2013, and it actually installed 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting Pack and 4.5.1 SDK. A search on MS shows a SDK package for Windows 8.1 under 4.5.1, but no SDK under 4.5.2. Does that mean the SDK tools are only at 4.5.1, not in 4.5.2?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there is that much difference.

Comment: There just is no SDK version that has 4.5.2.  That version of .NET shipped after VS2013.  There is exceedingly little reason to target it, it is just a minor maintenance release with very few useful additions.  And it hasn't been debugged all that well, that happens when nobody uses it.  This LC.exe problem is also mentioned in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442450/why-is-visual-studio-2013-using-the-wrong-sdktoolspath-for-lc-exe).

Answer (score 2):

the latest LC.exe is contained in Windows SDK for Windows 8.1, which is installed by Visual Studio 2013. Unfortunately, it is installed under the folder name "NETFX 4.5.1 Tools". This is confusing because when .Net environment 4.5.2 comes out, people would expect a folder of "NETFX 4.5.2 Tools". Turns out, there is NO 4.5.2 tools. A page from MSDN explains what's included in where fairly clearly: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/p/dotnet_sdks.aspx#.