# can not compile 64bit a class library project when a web service is refrenced

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit

I have a class library project in VS2010. When I want to compile as 64-bit, the following error raises:

> An attempt was made to load an assembly with an incorrect format:
>   D:\ChilkatDotNet4.dll.

But when I remove web service from project, it compiles successfully. (The chilkat DLL is 64bit)

Any idea?

Comment: is this a static library or a library for windows mobile 7 ?

Comment: Is this anyway related to what you are caught with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746372/sgen-doesnt-work-after-upgrading-from-vs2008-to-vs2010