# Problems with sgen.exe & Oracle.DataAccess.dll (Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2012, sgen, sgen.exe

We tried to migrate our webservice project to Visual Studio 2012 from Visual Studio 2010. The project uses the Oracle.DataAccess.dll (v 11.2.0.3 32 and 64 Bit) and we create *.XmlSerializers.dll with sgen.exe.

The sgen.exe always fails to create the XmlSerailizer.dll for the project that contains the Oracle.DataAccess.dll. We need to build the solution as AnyCPU.

The error message we receive is the following:
SGEN : error : An attempt was made to load an assembly with an incorrect format: c:\oracle\x64\product\11.2.0\client_1\ODP.NET\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll.

Even only a side by side installation of Visual Studio 2010 & 2012 makes it impossible to build the Webservice project in either of the studios.

All our attempts to find a solution to the problem have failed so far.
Does anybody have a similar constellation and found a solution to the problem?

Comment: Wild guess: it's like this but 2010/2012 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746372/sgen-doesnt-work-after-upgrading-from-vs2008-to-vs2010

Comment: Oracle's refusal to use the GAC is some sort of evil scheme to give their consultants a business opportunity.  .NET build tools are 32-bit, they can't load the 64-bit version of the Oracle assemblies.  How sgen.exe can even find that version is unclear to me, fuslogvw.exe can give insight.